# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EX when Application.Workbooks.Add()

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vb.net, vsto

Excel 2010 throws above exception for command `Application.Workbooks.Add()`. However `Application.Workbooks.Count()` works.

This issue is new since I got Excel 2016 and Excel 2010 installed on parallel on my machine. Currently we do have users where the VSTO Add-in is working while both versions are installed side-by-side and we do have users where it isn't working at all because of above issue.

Do you have any idea what we can do?

Comment: Can you open both 2010 and 2016 from the Start Button?  What happens if you double click on an xlsx file from windows explorer?  What happen is you double click on an xls (Excel 2003) with no x)?  The Workbooks add with no destination opens a new workbook.  So the error should be able to be repeated just opening a new workbook.  I want to see what happens if you open an existing as well as opening a new workbook manually.

Comment: yes, I can open both excel version with Windows Start button.

I can't set with which version xlsx and xls files should be opened by double click. this is also working fine.

Comment: Does the [VSTO runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54251) installed on [all computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-install-the-visual-studio-tools-for-office-runtime-redistributable?view=vs-2019)? Try to update it on the PC where solution doesn't work.

Comment: When you get a failure does a new instance of Excel Open.  Either a new Workbook in the Existing ICON or a new ICON.  Does a worksheet appear in the new instance?     Are you using the Interop?  If you are using the Interop than a new Interop has to be installed for 2016.  You probably have the Interop for 2010.

Comment: If you built the VSTO addin on the machine with Excel 2016, it's referencing those DLLs. It may not work on machines with 2010 installed.

Comment: yes, VSTO runtime is installed on all machines.

No, there is no new excel application starting when the failure happens. However in Excel 2016 a new app is starting each time an Unser double-click-opens a Excel file, while this is not the case in Excel 2010 (which afaik is standard behavior).

Yes, we use Excel interop commands for the VSTO Add-In. There are two versions of Visual Studio Tools for Office Design-Time Adaptor for Excel available on developer machine (I guess these are coming with visual studio). However I can reproduce the error with both.

Comment: I build the Add-In with Excel 2010, then we switched to Excel 2016 and everything is working just fine for users with only Office 2010, users with only Office 2016 and some users which having both installed. However for some users we see above issue. Therefore I am not sure if it could be a dll-reference issue.